# Sitecore 9.2 Virtual User Authentication and SessionId Cookie

Tags: configuration, security, pipelines

On the project I'm working on, we have chosen to use `Sitecore 9.2 XM` with `Identity Server` disabled.  Where in the `pipeline` should I expect to see the `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie get generated to be sent to the user?  The behavior I'm currently seeing is that is cookie value never gets set or sent back to the user.  The only way I get this cookie is by logging into the `shell`.

As you can imagine, the result is that data related to session is not being persisted from one visit to the next since `ASP.NET` is creating a new session on each request.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I had a moment of mental ability...

It turns out I was not writing anything to session.  As one would expect, since nothing was being written to session, ASP.NET had no need to write a SessionId cookie to the response.

I hope my brain fart helps others.  LOL